# If an airline cancels an aircraft order, can a different airline acquire those options?

Tags: airline-operations, aircraft-manufacturer

Let's say Airline A placed an order for an aircraft a while back. After a bit of time, Airline A decides it no longer has a need for the aircraft and decides to cancel the order. Meanwhile, Airline B decides it wants to buy said aircraft but doesn't want to go to the back of the delivery line. Is there a process where Airline B can take Airline A's spot in the delivery queue? I vaguely remember seeing something like this happen before, but cannot find any sources.

Comment: Anything is possible but remember that a purchase contract is between the mfr and the buyer. Airline A cannot transfer the contract obligations to airline B (because the mfr has an obligation to A and cannot usually transfer that obligation on the mfrs behalf), airline B would have to negotiate the queue position with the mfr when it purchases or assumes the contract. Mfrs may use this as a selling tactic when somebody cancels a contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general yes, but depending on how close the aircraft was to completion they have to live with a different cabin and cockpit layout than what they are used to or would had ordered themselves.